# Object to nested array

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need to convert the object to a nested array. I need a nested array to insert multiple mysql query.

Here is an example my object

```
item = [
{ id: '100',
  classid: '500',
  instanceid: '0',
  amount: '1',
  pos: 1,
  appid: '730'},
{ id: '104',
  classid: '987',
  instanceid: '3',
  amount: '5',
  pos: 2,
  appid: '730'}]
```

With the above date I need nested array without amount and pos.
I was looking for a solution, but I could not find

Answer (score 0):

It was very simple, I apologize for the problem and spam